# "They seem to like" in French: "semblent aiment"?

Tags: anglais, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

How do you say "They seem to like ..." in French? Is "Semblent aiment ..." correct? And, am I right in thinking that this sentence should be in subjunctive mood (for its uncertainty) or should it be in indicative mood? (Now, in this particular case, the third person plural of these verbs are identical in present subjunctive and present indicative, but the questions still stands.)

---

Bonjour. Comment dit-on "They seem to like ..." en français?

"Semblent aiment"? Au subjonctif ou indicatif?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"<s>Semblent aiment</s>" is missing some words.

"*They seem to like*" might be translated by:

> - "Il semble qu'ils aiment"
> - "Ils semblent aimer"
> - "On dirait qu'ils aiment"

Subjunctive is appropriate here as there is uncertainty.

---

Il manque quelques mots à « <s>Semblent aiment</s> ».

« *They seem to like* » pourrait se traduire par

> - « Il semble qu'ils aiment »
> - « Ils semblent aimer »
> - « On dirait qu'ils aiment »

Le mode subjonctif est indiqué ici puisqu'il y a doute.

Comment: Right. I'm trying to say "The French seem to like". Should that be "Le Français (Ils) semblent aiment" or "Le Français semblent aimer", judging from your second translation suggestion? *Aimer* in infinitive? No congruence?

Comment: Just like in English, an infinitive is required. "Ils semblent aiment" is as incorrect a "he seems likes" would be.

Comment: Either "Le Français semble aimer" or "Les Français semblent aimer" would be good for what you're trying to tell. I prefer the second one though...